# Detrending these time series

Tags: r, time-series, arima, vector-autoregression, trend

I have the following time series. Its clearly not a simple linear trend. I want to explore the relationship among these variables using a VAR, or even a time-varying VAR. The biggest issue in my data is stationarity. I prefer not to difference as it removes the long-term trends as well.

What would be the best way to detrend them (I'm using R) and/or do my analyses?

[image]